# Cucumber: Multiline arguments using "step" method inside a step definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, cucumber, factory-bot

The factory_girl Cucumber helpers are cool. I love that this works:

```
Given the following users exist:
  | Name | Email            |
  | Alan | alan@example.com |
  | Bob  | bob@example.com  |
```

But I can't work out how to invoke them inside a step definition. For instance:

```
Given /the usual users exist/ do
  step "the following users exist:
    | Name | Email            |
    | Alan | alan@example.com |
    | Bob  | bob@example.com  |"
end
```

... throws `Your block takes 1 argument, but the Regexp matched 0 arguments. (Cucumber::ArityMismatchError)`.

What's the correct way to pass a multiline argument to another step using `step` inside a step definition?

**Edit:**
Source code's always handy. I found that the signature for `step` is `def step(name, multiline_argument=nil)`. Suggestive. Sadly, however,

```
step "the following users exist", "
    | Name | Email            |
    | Alan | alan@example.com |
    | Bob  | bob@example.com  |"
```

also fails with `undefined method 'hashes' for #<Cucumber::Ast::DocString:0xa9bf6f4> (NoMethodError)`. I'd still love to know how that's supposed to work.

However, there's a silver lining. I found another function `steps`, which is `def steps(steps_text)`, and that works. See answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not quite what I was looking for, but reading the source code reveals that the following works:

```
Given /the usual users exist/ do
  steps "Given the following users exist:
    | Name | Email            |
    | Alan | alan@example.com |
    | Bob  | bob@example.com  |"
end
```

Comment: @JustinSearls - Works perfectly for me, and has done for the past year.